# Spring Cloud Config Server - Configure the server to get common properties from one repository and application properties form a different repository

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have the following requirements:

- There is a git repo (commonRepo) with an application.yml file that contains properties which are common to all applications.
- There is another git repo (applicationRepo) with the applications' config files: app1.yml, app2.yml, etc.

The point of this is to have all common properties centralized in a repo with specific write permissions.

I need to configure Spring Cloud Config Server to read from both repos, with the following priority:

> applicationRepo:appX.yml > applicationRepo:application.yml >
>   commonRepo:application.yml

Is it possible to configure it to do that?

Comment: Sadly, I haven't tried that myself, but in case you haven't found anything helpful online, try the official docs http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.1.RELEASE/ - they have a section on Pattern Matching and Multiple Repositories, which might help you

Comment: It doesn't. The multiple repositories feature is meant to separate configuration by team. It stops once a match is found.

Comment: @spencergibb do you think it could be considered as a future feature? I think it's kind of necessary, in our company certain properties such as database config (url, db user, db password) can only be set up by a infrastructure team, that's why we need them to be in a different repo that only allows that team to update the props

Comment: Actually, we now have a composite environment where this could work that I'd forgotten about.

Comment: Great! I just found it in the documentation, thanks for pointing at it.

Comment: @codependent, How can i do the same with PCF config server.. Have the slimier requirement like yours and we use PCF config server instead spring config server. Please help me here.. thanks lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my initial config:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///home/codependent/git/scc-dev
          repos:
            dev:
              pattern: '*/dev'
              uri: file:///home/codependent/git/scc-dev
            pre:
              pattern: '*/pre'
              uri: file:///home/codependent/git/scc-pre
            pro:
              pattern: '*/pro'
              uri: file:///home/codependent/git/scc-pro
```

There is a default repo in case there's no environment match and three repos depending on a pattern.

The idea is have another base repo (with the lowest priority) that would always be loaded and also depends on the environment. This base repo contains an application.yml with shared properties managed by a different team.

Apparently there's no way of doing it via yml properties so I had to define the beans manually, this is the code necessary to do it:

```
    @Bean
    public EnvironmentRepository baseEnvironmentRepository(){
        ConfigurableEnvironment ce = new StandardServletEnvironment();
        PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository devRepo = new PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository("file:///home/codependent/git/scc-ops-dev");
        devRepo.setEnvironment(ce);
        devRepo.setForcePull(false);
        devRepo.setPattern(new String[]{ "*/dev" });

        PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository preRepo = new PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository("file:///home/codependent/git/scc-ops-pre");
        preRepo.setEnvironment(ce);
        preRepo.setForcePull(false);
        preRepo.setPattern(new String[]{ "*/pre" });

        PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository proRepo = new PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository("file:///home/codependent/git/scc-ops-pro");
        proRepo.setEnvironment(ce);
        proRepo.setForcePull(false);
        proRepo.setPattern(new String[]{ "*/pro" });

        Map<String, PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("dev", devRepo);
        map.put("pre", preRepo);
        map.put("pro", proRepo);

        MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository multiple = new MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository(new StandardServletEnvironment());
        multiple.setUri("file:///home/codependent/git/scc-ops-dev");
        multiple.setRepos(map);
        multiple.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return multiple;
    }

    @Bean
    public EnvironmentRepository environmentRepository(){
        ConfigurableEnvironment ce = new StandardServletEnvironment();
        PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository devRepo = new PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository("file:///home/codependent/git/scc-dev");
        devRepo.setEnvironment(ce);
        devRepo.setForcePull(false);
        devRepo.setPattern(new String[]{ "*/dev" });

        PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository preRepo = new PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository("file:///home/codependent/git/scc-pre");
        preRepo.setEnvironment(ce);
        preRepo.setForcePull(false);
        preRepo.setPattern(new String[]{ "*/pre" });

        PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository proRepo = new PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository("file:///home/codependent/git/scc-pro");
        proRepo.setEnvironment(ce);
        proRepo.setForcePull(false);
        proRepo.setPattern(new String[]{ "*/pro" });

        Map<String, PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("dev", devRepo);
        map.put("pre", preRepo);
        map.put("pro", proRepo);

        MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository multiple = new MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository(new StandardServletEnvironment());
        multiple.setUri("file:///home/codependent/git/scc-dev");
        multiple.setRepos(map);
        multiple.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return multiple;
    }
```